# Renderscript, image processing, assigning pixel values from a precomputed array

Tags: android, image-processing, renderscript

I have an array of precomputed intensity (computed using a fuzzy logic inference system on a desktop machine). Now I want to use this array as a lookup table for a contrast enhancement application on android, using renderscript.

What I want to do, at a highlevel  is to process every pixel in an image, and using the lookup table create a new image where the pixel at the corresponding position has the value looked up in the array. Before I start looking at how to implement this, is this even feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is feasible and this is something RS can handle with no problems.  You'll need to provide your RS "kernel" with the pre-computed array data as either a separate `Allocation` or just a data array.

This talk will help get you started: https://youtu.be/3ynA92x8WQo